# Switch Case with If Statements - Javascript & Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, switch-statement, keypress

What's wrong with this code? It's supposed to capture all clicks within #ts_container div that are either buttons or anchors. It is also supposed to capture keypress events.

I'm trying to apply an If statement within each case to determine if keypress and / or click and if so it rewrites the new div name into the expressions at the bottom of the switch case and then the current text will fade out and new text fade in.  W/o Keypress it works fine. As it is written now, it still works fine when you click but I can't get it to trigger on keypress events and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#ts_container').on('click keypress', 'button, a', function(e) {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var fade_out;
        var fade_in;

        switch (id) {
            case 'start':
                if ((e.type === 'keypress' && e.which === 13) || (e.type == 'click')) {
                    fade_out = '#start_1';
                    fade_in = '#step_0';
                }
                break;
            case 'AC':
                if ((e.type === 'keypress' && e.which === 49 || e.which === 97) || (e.type == 'click')) {
                    fade_out = '#step_0';
                    fade_in = '#step_AC_1';
                }
                break;
            case 'step_AC_Continue_1':
                if ((e.type === 'keypress' && e.which === 13) ||
                    (e.type == 'click')) {
                    fade_out = '#step_AC_1';
                    fade_in = '#step_AC_2';
                }
                break;
            case 'Step_0_Option_1':
                if ((e.type === 'keypress' && e.which === 50 || e.which === 98) || (e.type == 'click')) {
                    fade_out = '#step_0';
                    fade_in = '#step_Heat_1';
                }
                break;
            case 'step_AC_Option_1':
                if ((e.type === 'keypress' && e.which === 49 || e.which === 97) || (e.type == 'click')) {
                    fade_out = '#step_AC_2';
                    fade_in = '#step_AC_3';
                }
                break;
            case 'step_AC_Option_2':
                if ((e.type === 'keypress' && e.which === 50 || e.which === 98) || (e.type == 'click')) {
                    fade_out = '#step_AC_2';
                    fade_in = '#step_AC_solution_electrical';
                }
                break;
            case 'step_AC_Option_3':
                if ((e.type === 'keypress' && e.which === 51 || e.which === 99) || (e.type == 'click')) {
                    fade_out = '#step_AC_2';
                    fade_in = '#step_AC_circuit_breaker';
                }
                default:
                    fade_out = '#start_1';
                    fade_in = '#step_0';
        }

        $(fade_out).fadeTo('fast', 0).css('visibility', 'hidden')
            .css('display', 'none');

        $(fade_in).delay(800).css('visibility', 'visible')
            .css('display', 'block').fadeTo('slow', 1);
    });
});
```

Comment: Please add a correctly indented code, it's hard to debug code like this.
try to add a debuger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parenthesis in most of your `if` statements aren't correct:

```
if ((e.type === 'keypress' && e.which === 49 || e.which === 97) || (e.type == 'click'))
if ((e.type === 'keypress' && e.which === 50 || e.which === 98) || (e.type == 'click'))
if ((e.type === 'keypress' && e.which === 49 || e.which === 97) || (e.type == 'click'))
if ((e.type === 'keypress' && e.which === 50 || e.which === 98) || (e.type == 'click'))
if ((e.type === 'keypress' && e.which === 51 || e.which === 99) || (e.type == 'click'))
```

`&&` takes priority over `||`, so those end up being:

```
if (((e.type === 'keypress' && e.which === x) || e.which === y) || (e.type == 'click'))
```

Change them to:

```
if (e.type === 'keypress' && (e.which === x || e.which === y) || e.type == 'click')
```

Which translates to:

- It has to be a `keypress` with code `x` or `y`, OR
- It's a click event.

---

You're also registering the event handler on `button` and `a` elements:

```
.on('click keypress', 'button, a'
```

These generally don't listen to keyboard events unless you're already focusing on'm.

A fix would be to declare the function separately, and to register the handler like this:

```
function handleEvent(e) {
    // Do stuf
}

$('#ts_container').on('click', 'button, a', handleEvent);
$(window).on('keypress', handleEvent);
```

Comment: Hi Cerbrus, thanks for the assist. Unfortunately this didn't work either it still doesn't trigger keypresses.

Comment: Yea, I found another issue. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Actually it didn't do the trick. It fires off on the first case, but doesn't work after that. When 1st case (first page loads) and press the continue button or enter on keyboard it fires off hiding the first page and loading the second page. But on second page, nothing works.

Comment: Here's an example of it in action https://jsfiddle.net/0xvdsoem/

Comment: `$(this).attr("id");` is referencing the wrong object there... You'll need to get that differently, for the keyboard case...

Comment: If that were the case, why would the switch case trigger on enter key for first result? In any case, I switched the case from ID variable to true and it still doesn't do anything after first page.

Comment: You were right about the ID. First page wasn't actually triggering, it was the default case that was triggering which happened to be same as page 1.

There were multiple problems still. First, I had the variables outside of the function when they needed to be inside. I also added an If statement to store IDs in the variable ID, and else for Keypresses in the same variable.

Then I realized, I needed cases for the Keypresses in order for it to trigger. This eliminated the need for all of the complex && || if statements in each case. 

Thx again! - https://jsfiddle.net/b4wd08qj/4/